# Chrome Extension: changing Github's favicon

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to select and change github's favicon to a different favicon.

When I inspect Github, the favicon shows up as:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" class="js-site-favicon" href="https://assets-cdn.github.com/favicon.ico">
```

I then try to select it and change it but it doesn't work.

```
var link = document.querySelector("link[rel*='icon']");
link.type = "image/x-icon";
link.rel = "shortcut icon";
link.href = chrome.runtime.getURL("img/sampleFavicon.png");
```

I tried doing the same thing on `w3schools.com` which has the same thing `(<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">)`and it does successfully change the favicon.

Is there a better selector I could use that would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of issues here:

1. github.com pages have multiple elements corresponding to the query: `link[rel*='icon']`. You want to update at least the last one (or all of them). You can use: `document.querySelectorAll` method to get all of them.
2. I haven't try to update the favicon from a Chrome Extension but directly from Chrome Dev Tools. When trying to update the favicon with a external image like: `link.href = 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d'`
   it triggers the following error:

   ```
   Refused to load the image 'https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d' 
   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
   "img-src 'self' data: assets-cdn.github.com identicons.github.com collector.githubapp.com github-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com *.githubusercontent.com".
   ```

And a work around here would be to convert your favicon into a base 64 string, and then do:
`link.href = 'data:image/x-icon;base64,AJHDFH....';`

Comment: This works, thanks! Would websites usually use `link[rel*='icon']` and `link[rel*='shortcut icon']` for their favicon? Is there any other qeurys I should use?

Comment: Your initial query: `link[rel*='icon']` would find `<link rel="shortcut icon" />` so I feel like it would cover most of the favicon definitions. You could always have multiple queries in `document.querySelectorAll` like: `document.querySelectorAll('link[rel=icon], link[rel="shortcut icon"]')`

Comment: Ah thanks! I've also just been having a problem selecting Google's favicon (ex: google.com.) I've made another post about it, but in short, Google pages don't seem to have the `icon` or `shortcut icon`, and I can't find how they link their favicon.

Comment: I believe, browsers will default to pick up `/favicon.ico` if there is not `link` tag defined. (Here is google favicon: https://www.google.com/favicon.ico)